# Java socket.io client portage

Tags: java, node.js, socket.io, client

I got the nodeJS simpliest server running :

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
 
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
 
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});
 
http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

I got [this usage example](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java#usage) for the socket.io client java portage from the socket.io official github:

```js
socket = IO.socket("http://localhost:3000");
socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        socket.emit("foo", "hi");
        socket.disconnect();
    }

}).on("event", new Emitter.Listener() {

    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {}

}).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {}

});
socket.connect();
```

But the server is not receiving any connection, and the client either..
Someone already suceed to make it work?
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind this post, I just created a new project, pasted all the same code and it works... My project was probably corrupted in a way or another...
Sorry